# CoreData with CloudKit configuration path

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, swift5

I wanted to update my CoreData app to an iCloudKit app, and wanted to do this with the new CloudKit feature to tenable CloudKit for existing CoreData apps. I followed the [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit#see-also) to do this (the second part: updating an existing Xcode Project. But I find the store descriptions paths for my scores but I don't know how to find these paths.

Here are the paths I can't find
[image: URL Paths I can't find]

and my CoreData Model with its configurations
[image: My CoreData model]

Does anyone know how I can find theses url path to Connect with the configurations ?

Thank's a lot

Comment: I too am having trouble setting configurations, so one of my stores syncs to iCloud and the others do not and I have a feeling it has something to do with these paths you've highlighted. Not sure how to proceed the below answer did not help. error `Fatal error: Could not load persistent stores. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file couldn’t be saved." UserInfo={reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found myself the solution:

the path needed is the local path to the sqlite database created for each configuration as:

Local store: /files/local.sqlite

Cloud store: /files/cloud.sqlite

Answer (score 3):

I can solve this problem. the answer should be like this:

```
 let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "WrongQuestion")
 let address = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WrongQuestion", ofType: ".momd")
 let localStoreLocation = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(address!)/Default.sqlite")

 let localStoreDescription =
                    NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: localStoreLocation)
 localStoreDescription.configuration = "Default"
```

path should be your CoreDataModel's address + "configuration name .sqlite"